# Vertical Dots + symbol inside one equation

Tags: math-mode

I need to type the following equation but I don't have an idea how I could include those vertical dots + symbol inside the equation at exactly that position.

[image]

Comment: possible with tikz -- upload your code --

Comment: @jsbibra There is absolutely no need for TikZ to do this, just use `\overset` from `amsmath`. But I agree that a MWE is necessary.

Comment: for logical proof I recommend bussproofs.sty. Here is the documentation: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/bussproofs/BussGuide2.pdf